# How to hide default keyboard when click on menu?

Tags: android

I have tried several methods for this website by inserting the code in the `onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu)` without success. I want to hide the keyboard when I click the menu button.

I have three EditText where I write some data, and options to insert / delete / modify a database, are on the menu, but if I click, the keyboard does not hide automatically.

I have something like this:

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);

    if(this.getCurrentFocus() != null && this.getCurrentFocus() instanceof EditText){
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
    }
    return true;
}
```

It only works the first time I press the menu button.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the code to `onOptionsItemSelected` instead

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {  
    .....
     if(this.getCurrentFocus() != null && this.getCurrentFocus() instanceof EditText){
         InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
     }
  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another place you can put the `InputMethodManager` code is in the `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` callback like this:

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
    return true;
}
```

You may prefer this if you want the keyboard hidden regardless of whether the user actually subsequently clicks on any of the menu items.