# Slow navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

My navigation drawer lags when I open complex view. Here is my MenuActivity code:

```
public class MenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
private Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
    // Set a Toolbar to replace the ActionBar.
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    // Set the menu icon instead of the launcher icon.
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    // Setup drawer view
    findViewById(R.id.building_status_fragment).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.news_fragment).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.register_fragment).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.phone_view).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.services_fragment).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.contacs_fragment).setOnClickListener(this);
    // first init
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new BuildingStatusFragment()).commit();
    setTitle(getString(R.string.title_building_progress)); // toolbar.setTitle dont work, hm
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    mDrawer.closeDrawers();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.building_status_fragment:
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new BuildingStatusFragment());
            toolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.title_building_progress));
            break;
        case R.id.news_fragment:
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new NewsFeedFragment());
            toolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.title_news));
            break;
        case R.id.register_fragment:
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new RegisterFragment());
            toolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.title_look));
            break;
        case R.id.services_fragment:
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new ServicesFragment());
            toolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.title_services));
            break;
        case R.id.contacs_fragment:
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new ContactsFragment());
            toolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.title_contacts));
            break;
        case R.id.phone_view:
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:74996782873")));
            break;
    }
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721049/how-to-hide-default-keyboard-when-click-on-menu
            if(getCurrentFocus() != null && getCurrentFocus() instanceof EditText){
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
            }
            mDrawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

I have "complex" view with 2 images:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:scrollbars="none">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/auto" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toptext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
            android:background="#B300A3DA"
            android:paddingLeft="6dp"
            android:paddingRight="6dp"
            android:text="Покупка"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toptext"
            android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:background="#B300A3DA"
            android:paddingLeft="6dp"
            android:paddingRight="6dp"
            android:text="машиномест"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <!--Костыль-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp">
            <!--Костыль-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/auto_form"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#B3000000"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="7dp"
                android:paddingLeft="50dp"
                android:paddingRight="50dp"
                android:paddingTop="7dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Посмотреть"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="предложение"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/rights" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toptext2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
            android:background="#B300A3DA"
            android:paddingLeft="6dp"
            android:paddingRight="6dp"
            android:text="Оформление"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toptext2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:background="#B300A3DA"
            android:paddingLeft="6dp"
            android:paddingRight="6dp"
            android:text="прав собственности"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
        <!--Костыль-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp">
            <!--Костыль-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/rights_form"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#B3000000"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="7dp"
                android:paddingLeft="50dp"
                android:paddingRight="50dp"
                android:paddingTop="7dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Посмотреть"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="предложение"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And it lags every time when I open this fragment. Also I noticed that fragment with map view also have some lags. I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20164633/navigation-drawer-is-slow-with-complex-view) and looks like I should do all my work after navigation drawer is closed (if I call mDrawer.closeDrawers() before fragment transaction isn't it the same??), but what the reason for lags if I open drawer when fragment with complex view is already initialized? It is very strange for me.

Also debugger said that uithread takes 2 much work and skip frames.So should I optimize my "complex" fragments or optimize navigation drawer appears? And how? Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw your code and following are the corrections I want to make

1. Load bitmaps off the Ui Thread(instead of mentioning large bitmaps in xml  use a place holder and start loading in on resume)
2. Use Scaled down version of bitmaps if possible
3. You can load bitmaps in RGB565 Format if they are not transparent, it will half the size of bitmap at almost no quality loss.
4. Don't set Background color for your Relative layout. It will never be displayed as Image will overdraw it. Overdrawing consumes processing power. It will help you speed up.

   5. Avoid unnecessary nesting of your layouts. Linear inside Linear, instead try RelativeLayout or [PercentRelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html)
   6. Try using getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(null); as you have set ScrollView background white.

I hope that's enough to speed your code up.

Comment: Thx!
So the only way is to fix my code in fragments to make navigation drawer open smooth ? And in my map view fragment I should also try to move all loading in background thread?

Comment: You can call getMapAsync for google maps and you have to provide onMapReady callback. You will be notified when you map is loaded(ready to use)

Comment: It is sad, but I still cant understand why then navigation drawer lags if I open menu when fragment is already loaded?

Comment: can you elaborate the issue and provide me your code so that I can see and tell what's the issue??

Answer (score 1):

i think you are using navigation drawer header background image, remove or change the navigation drawer header background image(small size), then try it once